# PHP Convert cents to dollars

Tags: php, numbers

I'm using Stripe Payment.
My prices are integers in cents:

```
050
1000
1250
2999
```

I manipulate those numbers with my own class and no problem with that.

I'm looking the way to convert those numbers (cents) in dollars (always with decimals even if .00) like following:

```
0.50
10.00
12.50
29.99
```

Any idea?

Comment: NumberFormatter http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

Comment: Thank you CD001. @Styphon You're not too lazy to write for nothing.

Comment: Fredmat @Styphon is correct. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . You should research enough before asking a question.

Comment: `closed as off-topic by` ...love the question, Stack rules are stupid in this direction.

Comment: This is a good programming question.  No code provided, but Stripe is a very important e-commerce technology and deals in cents, so numeric/cents conversion is a legit question.

Comment: I also think this question is relevant, as managing money values in floats can be quite unsafe: https://twitter.com/billkarwin/status/347561901460447232

Answer (score 24):

You can use `number_format()` in following way:

```
<?php

$value = 50;

echo number_format(($value /100), 2, '.', ' ');

?>
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/tHigs

For more reference read the below link

[number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 8):

You need to divide cents by 100 and use `number_format` function.

```
echo number_format($price/100, 2, '.', ' ');
```

Comment: It's an alternative I agree, but I choose NumberFormatter ;) Thanks!